# Can anyone tell me about the Event Handler or Callback on switching of the front process on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, macos-carbon

I need to have the callback or some event handler which can help me, know front process is changed.

Mac: C++/Carbon. 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the `kEventAppFrontSwitched` event in the `kEventClassApplication` class. See [the Carbon Event Manager reference](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Carbon_Event_Manager_Ref/).